# インストール直後の Cassandra (Single-Node Cluster) が起動しません

Tags: java, linux, centos, cassandra

Cassandra 習得のため，シンプルな Single-Node Cluster でインストールし起動を試みましたが，起動が成功しません．

手順は[こちらのサイト（英文）](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cassandra-and-run-a-single-node-cluster-on-a-ubuntu-vps)に従いました．
ざっくり以下の手順です．

1. VirtualBox に CentOS7 で新規仮想マシンを構築
2. JDK をインストールし，/usr/local/java/ に置き，パスを通す
3. Apache Cassandra をインストールし，/root/cassandra/ に置き，lib や log の必要なディレクトリを作り，Cassandra に書込み権限を付与

Root user で以下の起動コマンド

```
# sh ~/cassandra/bin/cassandra
```

すると以下のメッセージ

```
Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user.
If you really want to force running Cassandra as root, use -R command line option.
```

-R オプションで再度，起動コマンド

```
# sh ~/cassandra/bin/cassandra -R
```

以下のエラーメッセージとなります．

```
# [0.000s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:/root/cassandra/bin/../logs/gc.log instead.
intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

JVM 関連の問題のようですが，行き詰ってしまっています．
原因，解決法等，お分かりでしたらご教示お願いします．

環境は以下の通りです．

Windows 10
VirtualBox 5.1.28
CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611
jdk-9.0.1
apache-cassandra-3.11.1

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/97930

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cassandraのバグが原因のようです。

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-13107

Java 9では未解決の問題となっていますが、Java 8であれば次のページに回避策が書いてあるようです。

http://tech.stolsvik.com/2010/01/linux-java-thread-priorities-workaround.html

もしくは、エラーメッセージ

> Running Cassandra as root user or group is not recommended - please start Cassandra using a different system user.

の通り、rootユーザー以外で実行してみて下さい。

Comment: ご指摘のとおり dk1.8.0_151 で問題なく起動しました！（ちなみに Java 9 で root ユーザ以外では解決しませんでした）ありがとうございます！